# Cannot find module "./some_path" in typescript. Except no other solutions work

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, ecmascript-6, typing

I have a folder `classes` that contains `book.ts`, `library.ts` and `person.ts` along with an `index.d.ts`

The first 3 files are all class files. Here is an example, `book.ts`

```
export default class DefaultBook implements Book {

    constructor(
        readonly id: number,
        readonly name: string,
        readonly author: string
    ) { }

}
```

The other two class files are layed out roughly the same, but most importantly they all have `export default` in front of the one and only class in their file

My `index.d.ts` file looks like this:

```
export { default as DefaultBook } from "./book";
export { default as DefaultLibrary } from "./library";
export { default as DefaultPerson } from "./person";
```

And in my `index.ts` main file, I import the classes like so

```
import { DefaultLibrary, DefaultBook } from "./classes"
```

and define a book object like so

```
const aBook = new DefaultBook(
    12,
    "Harry Potter",
    "J. K. Rowling"
)
```

**Error Explanation**

When I run `tsc index.ts` and `node index.js`. The following error is outputted

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './classes'
```

The error code is `MODULE_NOT_FOUND`

Weirdly, I have a folder called `types` which has a similar layout to `classes` except the class files are type files intead, exporting namespaces and interfaces (still export default). I have an `index.d.ts` file in `types` as well and import them in `index.ts`, the same way I am trying to import `classes`.

VSCode doesn't see my code as having an error only upon compilation

**What I've tried**

- `npm install -g typescript` to try and update typescript
- deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` then running `npm init` again
- `moduleResolution: "node"` inside of `tsconfig.json` in `compilerOptions`
- adding `input: ["classes"]` to `tsconfig.json`

Quick Note: I can successfully import and use the classes in `index.ts` by doing

```
import DefaultBook from "./classes/book";
```

So I know that it is not an issue with my class structure or exporting methods
Although it may be an issue with `.d.ts` files not supporting classes, but from my research I don't think this is the case

Any ideas?

Comment: `index.d.ts` looks suspicious to me. Might it be `index.ts`?

Comment: I've had no issues import the `./types/index.d.ts`, only with `./classes/index.d.ts`
Maybe its because `index.d.ts` files dont support classes? Ill try renaming the file.
I renamed the `./classes/index.d.ts` to `./classes/collator.d.ts` and updated the import statement accordingly, but still the same error message.

Comment: Types and classes are different things (Class is also a type). Types belong to typesciprt so they exist virtually but classes are not.

Comment: Oooh that what you meant in the first comment. So classes are not acceptable to use in a `.d.ts` file and to collate them you should just use `index.ts`. Alright, that worked perfectly. thanks

Comment: Classes can be defined in d.ts file if you have some javascript module backing that up. Some libraries don't provide typescript definitions. But type definitions in d.ts files remain virtual.

Comment: I think its because the library class uses the `Array.include()` method which I dont think is available in earlier ES versions. Thanks again